# Laravel 4 URL::action error

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller called CharactersController.php in my controllers directory. Here are the two functions:

```
    public function search()
{
    return View::make('search.search');
}

public function post_search()
{
    $name = Input::get('character');
    $searchResult = Player::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->paginate(5);
    return View::make('search.post_search')
            ->with('name', $name)
            ->with('searchResult', $searchResult);
}
```

In the first function (`function search()`) I return a view. Here's the code of the view(just the form):

```
        <form id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right" action="{{ URL::action('CharactersController@post_search') }}" method="get">
        <div class="input-append spancustom">
            <input type="text" class="search-query" name="character" placeholder="Character/guild name">
            <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

When I try to run the form (to search) I get an `Unknown action [CharactersController@post_search].` error. I had this error before, I tried switching controllers, tried doing everything. But it didn't work. So I gave up.

Anyone who can solve it?

Comment: did you try run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange tried, got an error message that my composer build is old, that I need to self-update it. That's what I did. Tried to run it again, same thing happens.

Comment: It's not an error message. it's just an error message. The composer actually will proceed and finished the autoload in your case. It should have been.

Comment: In your routes.php file, put the `Route::get()` function in question on top.  If you have a `Route::controller()` method setup or something similar, it could be grabbing and redirecting the request before you want it to.

Comment: Nope, I just have these for the news index and news creation.. You can view my routes: http://paste.laravel.com/Kxb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that controller `RESTful?`

And Have you created a `Route::controller()` in the routes.php?

If it's not `RESTFul`, can you try removing `post_` in the method's title?

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually defined a route for the controller's method? You need to do that, else that pesky exception will be thrown when you call `URL::action()`

Comment: Yeah, didn't have one. But I don't want to have a post method, I want to have a get method, beacuse post would be annoying. Could I have two routes with get?

Comment: I don't know much about Laravel 3, but I'm assuming you're using the latest version (i.e. 4 at the time of this writing) because of the tags you put up. Basically, you can just call `Route::get('someurl', 'CharactersController@post_search')` and it should handle a `GET` request on `someurl` with the `post_search()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Function names need to be camelCased per [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md). Chnage post_search to postSearch

Comment: still doesn't work. I managed to make it work with an Route::post and then the postSearch, but I don't want to make it post. I want it to be get method, as before, but I can't change the action in the form without errors. says that controller method does not exist.

Comment: are you using something like: Route::get('url', ['uses' => 'CharactersController@postSearch']);

Comment: can you paste in your controller and the stack trace...I just tried using Route::get('characters/search', 'CharactersController@postSearch'); and it worked fine for in my setup